# Values in IF statements in Excel being added instead of Exchanged

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I am using this function in my Excel document:

`=IF(E18<=24,+G68)+IF(E18<=36,+G69)`

and instead of changing out the value of `E18`the values of `G68` and `G69` are added.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `E18`? Also what do you mean "...instead of changing out the value of `E18`"?  What are you trying to do?  It looks like currently, `E18` is `<=24`...

Comment: Can you share example of input and desired output? I suggest using cells such as `A1`, `B1`...

Answer (score 0):

You want to nest the IF()s:

```
=IF(E18<=24,G68,IF(E18<=36,G69,"Greater than 36"))
```

By adding them together with the `+` you are saying any number less than or equal to 24 will cause both of the IF()s to return TRUE and it will then add the two resultants together.

By nesting if it is less than or equal to 24 then the only value that is returned is G28.  The other IF is only looked at if the value is greater than 24.